# isDivisible function in lambda calculus for Church numerals

Tags: programming, lambda-calculus

After trying without success for several days to find a proper software/website that can correctly simplify lambda terms (see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4779317/checking-equivalence-of-lambda-terms)), I ended up deciding to use JavaScript to do the same. The primary code that I set up was [this](http://tpcg.io/_7ED5UF). However, when I tried to create a function that checks whether a Church-encoded numeral is divisible by another and returns a Church boolean as a result, I came into a problem.

The lambda function I created was a sort of recursive combinator like this:
$$rec:=\lambda{abf}.greaterThanOrEqual(a)(b)(\,f(subtract(a)(b))(b)(f)\,)(isZero(a))$$
$$isDivisible:=\lambda{mn}.rec(m)(n)(rec)$$
My idea was this: to check if $m$ is divisible by $n$, subtract $n$ from $m$ and repeat this till the result is less than $n$. At that time check if the result is $0$. If it is zero, then return True, else return False.
Now the problem I ran into was this: JavaScript is *not* a lazy compiler, so it decided to solve the recursive part first and got locked into a series of infinite $\beta$-reductions, with no $\beta$-normal form in sight. However, if the compiler had decided to try each recursion step before the entire simplification, it would have reduced the term to a normal form.

So my problems are:

> **Is the recursive combinator I have written correct? That is, does it truly check divisibility?**

> **If it is correct, can anyone suggest a better option for software based lambda term simplification? That is, I will just write the lambda terms and they will be simplified to normal forms (if possible)**

Comment: Your term seems correct to me. What you are looking for is a tool performing *(weak) head reduction*; you can apply a specific reduction strategy by hand here: https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~rmk35/lambda_calculus/lambda_calculus.html.

Comment: @sparusaurata thanks a lot, the link is quite good

Comment: @sparusaurata actually, to tell the truth, right after posting the question, I've realised that it is always better to work things out by hand. So going to go back to the classical way: a pen, a paper and my mind.

Comment: I completely agree! ;-)